# How can I create an array of nulls

Tags: c#

I want to be able to create an array of booleans and want all values to be set to `null`. I tried the following but it didn't work:

```
Response = new bool[999]
```

This just creates an array of false's

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A `bool` can never be null - only true or false. However, a `bool?` (`Nullable<bool>`) can. Try this:

```
Response = new bool?[999];
```

Answer (score 3):

`bool` can't be `null`

But `bool?`, or, `Nullable<bool>` can.

```
Response = new Nullable<bool>[999];
```

Answer (score 1):

simple `bool` is not nullable type. Try `bool?`

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a [Nullable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0.aspx) array:

```
bool?[] nullableArray = new bool?[999];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
bool?[] Response = new bool?[999];
```